# Minimization of (z-xi)^2

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, median, minimize

If I want to find a `median` (it is equivalent to minimize a function |z - x<sub>i</sub>|), I can use the following `code snippet`:

```
std::vector<int> v{5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3};

std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size()/2, v.end());
std::cout << "The median is " << v[v.size()/2] << '\n';
```

Is there something like this, to find `"median"` for minimization of (z-x<sub>i</sub>)^2? That is, I want to find an element of the array in which the sum of these functions will be minimal.

Comment: Note that the order implied by `(z - xi)`<sup>2</sup> is equivalent to that implied by `|z - xi|` but using `abs(z - xi)` is likely to be more efficient than squaring `(z - xi)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, …, x<sub>n</sub> of integers, the real number z that minimizes ∑<sub>i∈{1,2,…,n}</sub> (z - x<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup> is the *mean* z* = (1/n) ∑<sub>i∈{1,2,…,n}</sub> x<sub>i</sub>. You want to call `std::min_element` with a comparator that treats x<sub>i</sub> as less than x<sub>j</sub> if and only if |n x<sub>i</sub> - n z*| < |n x<sub>j</sub> - n z*| (we use n z* = ∑<sub>i∈{1,2,…,n}</sub> x<sub>i</sub> to avoid floating-point arithmetic; there are ways to reduce the extra precision required).

Comment: you're absolutely right. I have found the derivative of function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the `nth_element()` according to a predicate comparing `(z - xi) ^ 2` you could just add the corresponding logic to the binary predicate you can optionally pass to `nth_element()`:

```
auto trans = [=](int xi){ return (z - xi) * (z - xi); };
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size() / 2, v.end(),
    [&](int v0, int v1) { return trans(v0) < trans(v1); });
```

From the question it isn't clearly whether `z` or `xi` is the changing variable. From the looks of it I assumed `xi` is meant to be `x`<sub>i</sub>. If `z` is changing, just rename the argument in the lambda `trans` (which I just also gave a `=` in the capture...).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this is little not that. `z` is not constant. `z` is an element of the array, where the minimum is reached.

Comment: @Denis You should clarify that in your question

Comment: So, `xi` is the constant? I had assumed that you mean `x`<sub>i</sub> to be the variable. Just rename the argument...

Comment: @DietmarKühl, thank you for your help. I understood everything.

Answer (score 2):

Your question works on at least two different levels: You're asking how to *implement* a certain algorithm idiomatically in C++11, and at the same time you're asking for an *efficient algorithm* for computing the mean of a list of integers.

You correctly observe that to compute the *median*, all we have to do is run the [QuickSelect algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) with `k` set equal to `n/2`. In the C++ standard library, QuickSelect is spelled [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element):

```
int v[] = { 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3 };

const int k = std::size(v) / 2; 
std::nth_element(std::begin(v), &v[k], std::end(v));  // mutate in-place
int median = v[v.size()/2];  // now the k'th element is
```

(For `std::size`, see proposal [N4280](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4280.pdf), [coming soon to a C++17 near you!](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4252.pdf)  Until then, use your favorite NELEM macro, or go back to using heap-allocated `vector`.)

This QuickSelect implementation doesn't really have anything to do with "finding array element *x<sub>k</sub>* such that ∑<sub>*i*</sub> |*x<sub>i</sub>* − *x<sub>k</sub>*| is minimized." I mean, it's mathematically equivalent, yes, but there's nothing in the *code* that corresponds to summing or subtracting integers.

The naïve algorithm to "find array element *x<sub>k</sub>* such that ∑<sub>*i*</sub> |*x<sub>i</sub>* − *x<sub>k</sub>|* is minimized" is simply

```
int v[] = { 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3 };

auto sum_of_differences = [v](int xk) {
    int result = 0;
    for (auto&& xi : v) {
        result += std::abs(xi - xk);
    }
    return result;
};

int median =
    std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](int xa, int xb) {
        return sum_of_differences(xa) < sum_of_differences(xb);
    });
```

This is a horribly inefficient algorithm, given that QuickSelect does the same job.
*However,* it's trivial to extend this code to work with any mathematical function you want to "minimize the sum of". Here's the same skeleton of code, but with the function "squared difference" instead of "difference":

```
int v[] = { 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3 };

auto sum_of_squared_differences = [v](int xk) {
    int result = 0;
    for (auto&& xi : v) {
        result += (xi - xk) * (xi - xk);
    }
    return result;
};

int closest_element_to_the_mean =
    std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](int xa, int xb) {
        return sum_of_squared_differences(xa) < sum_of_squared_differences(xb);
    });
```

In this case we can *also* find an improved algorithm; namely, compute the mean up front and only afterward scan the array looking for the element that's closest to that mean:

```
int v[] = { 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3 };

double actual_mean = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0.0) / std::size(v);

auto distance_to_actual_mean = [=](int xk) {
    return std::abs(xk - actual_mean);
};

int closest_element_to_the_mean =
    std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](int xa, int xb) {
        return distance_to_actual_mean(xa) < distance_to_actual_mean(xb);
    });
```

(P.S. – remember that *none* of the above code snippets should be used in practice, unless you're absolutely sure you don't need to care about integer overflow, floating-point rounding error, and a host of other mathy issues.)

Comment: your answer is great! Thank you!